# write into file with fputs and a for loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, fputs

i want to write into a file like this:

```
someText
{
  "Bob [m]" -> "Fed [m]";
  "Tom [m]" -> "Jenny [f]";
  ...
}
```

i have:

```
void file Write()
{
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("df.dot", "w");

    int i;

    fputs("someText\n", fp);
    fputs("{\n", fp);

    for (i = 1; i < 6; i++)
    {
        printf("  \"%s\" -> \"%s\";\n", sort[i].sorted1, sort[i].sorted2);
    }

    fputs("}\n", fp);

    fclose(fp);

}
```

The problem is the part with the for loop. The place where the fprints is located, it also has to be written with fputs. (fputs instead printf)

I think it is not possible, to do it this way with fputs. Is there another function() which makes this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for loop you used printf. You can use [fprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/) instead.
Or you can format string with [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) function and then write formated string using fputs.

Comment: THX a lot! Both working fine. Would you recommend one of those functions in practical use?

Comment: I think, it depends of what you want. fputs doesn't parse string and only writes it with '\n' at the end. fprintf writes a formatted string. You can use any of these functions, that is more convenient to you.